# Can non-administrator users share folders on the network on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, windows-networking

I'm working out a solution to a complicated file copying workflow in a laboratory environment. One solution hinges on normal users (who must not have administrator privileges) running a script that will share a directory owned by them on the network. Is this possible?

(I don't have access to any Windows 7 machines - otherwise I'd test this).

For context, the workflow would go something like this:

1. User logs in
2. Script runs automatically, sharing a directory (eg, My Documents\MyData) on the network as "MyData", read/writable by anyone. (In reality, this network has only one other PC, immediately next to it physically, so there's no actual security risk.)
3. On the other PC, a script mounts the "MyData" shared directory.
4. The same physical user saves data to this shared MyData folder from the second PC.
5. User logs out of both PCs, script unmounts everything.

Hence, the directory that the user is saving to from PC 2 is dependent on which user is logged in on PC 1.

If the rest of that isn't possible as well, please say so :)

Comment: Why not create a share for each user? Or one share with subfolders for each user? Is this domain environment or workgroup environment?

Comment: One share per user is another possibility. (More than 20 users though, could be a problem). PC #1 is on ActiveDirectory, PC 2 is only on the private network.